# How to do sequential processing in spark partition while updating lookup

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a job that needs some level of parallelism while doing sequential processing within each executor.

Scenario per partition

```
DF1(DF stating which all character should be in same group)
____________
A | B | p1  --> this row states that A and B should be in same group, p1 is partition
B | C | p1
C | D | p1
-----------

DF2 (known group of G1 & G2 for character A & D)
_______
A | G1
D | G2
--------
```

Now I want to run sequentially on DF1 and start grouping the character. For ex for first row in DF1 B will come into group G1 since A was in G1. Similarly when I process 2nd row C will come into group G1 because B was in G1 due to previous row. And then similarly D will also come into G1 because now C is in G1.

I am stuck at how to process this sequentially in spark without going OOM as the data can be huge.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your solving a graph problem.  You should look at [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#graph-builders) it helps represent the relationship you are discussing.  I can't promise it will work in memory but it's will help you represent the information in a better manner. (And it actually totally describes what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Will check graphX and get back if it can be used for my use case.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it solves the issue.